# Docker compose - multiple dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

So I'm new to Docker and I'm following the instructions listed out in [this cute article](https://blog.wodby.com/6-reasons-to-deploy-drupal-8-with-docker-how-to-guide-b2f073e61672). Essentially this flow involves a `pull` of default images for Drupal and mariadb, with the Drupal image being inherited from the official PHP image.

Now I'm looking at `docker-compose` to tie everything together.

1) From my understanding, we need to specify a Dockerfile for each container, but is there a way to have `docker-compose` use the Dockerfile that's bundled with the image itself, without having to explicitly create a Dockerfile?

In the example from the link, issuing `pull`s of the images for mariadb and Drupal end up using the Dockerfiles corresponding to those images itself.

2) In the example from the link, the containers are started by issuing `docker run` commands as such:

```
$ docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -e MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal8 -e MYSQL_USER=drupal8 -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=drupal8 -v mariadb:/var/lib/mysql -d --name mariadb mariadb
```

and

```
$ docker run --name drupal8 --link mariadb:mysql -p 80:80 -d drupal:8.0.1
```

Is there a way to add these run commands to the `docker-compose` flow, the end goal being to be able to just issue `docker-compose up -d`

Apologies for the naive questions but I'm a bit overwhelmed at this point.

Comment: You are on the right track. Here is another example that can be your starting point to write your `docker-compose.yml` file: [https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal/](https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal/).

Answer (score 0):

To use docker compose, you need a docker-compose.yml file.
This file will run your containers with a docker-compose up command.

In your compose file you can use directly images and not dockerfile. Depending of your needs.
Exemple

`version : '2'
services:
  cms:
    image: drupal:8.0.1
    ports :
      - 8080:8080
  database:
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - "./data:/var/lib/mysql"`
`

But even if you use a compose file like this

`version : '2'
services:
  stats:
    build: .
    ports :
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - "./app/:/usr/src/app"`

the command docker-compose up will build automaticaly your images.

Comment: check the doc https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#env_file

Answer (score 0):

This is the representation in docker-compose of your docker commands.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal8
      - MYSQL_USER=drupal8
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=drupal8
    volumes:
      - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
  drupal8:
    image: drupal:8.0.1
    links:
      - mariadb:mysql
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

To start all services (building them), usually when you change something on your code, run

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

To start them without build, using the cached image

```
docker-compose up -d
```

To stop them

```
docker-compose stop
```

To destroy them (needs a build after)

```
docker-compose down
```

You can also start just one container, for testing database for instance.

```
docker-compose up mariadb
```

And for see the logs of all containers together

```
docker-compose logs -f
```

Comment: Thanks @jonhid - but what I'm trying to do is essentially tie these commands up via composer. When I run the yml file you've given, I do get to the Drupal config page but while using the parameters (db name, db username etc), I get `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known.` - though when I issue the `docker run` commands individually, I'm able to configure Drupal correctly